# erasing part of grease pencil strokes

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I am fairly new to using blender for 2d animation, and just blender in general. I'm trying to use the grease pencil to animate. I feel like I'm missing something simple but cant find it out. I am trying to erase part of a stroke (created using size 25px F pen) with an eraser (15px point F eraser stroke). i can erase parts of the stroke, but there seems to be a limit on how small the section I can erase is. once i make the eraser under a certain number of pixels (somewhere around 40) the eraser point will not get any smaller. So I can erase but I cannot erase the line to have one end of it evenly match a perpendicular line. I hope this question is not too confusing. If anyone has any tips or solutions they would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's because in blender you don't erase pixels but the dots that form the stroke (more like a vector graphic program). If you go in Edit mode and switch the Selection Mode to only points you will see what I mean

Comment: Thank you so much @wilks this has helped me out so much and I am sure itll help me out with many problems in the future!